# How to prevent d3.drag().on('end' from firing .on('click'

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an svg element I'd like to be able to click and drag separately. As far as I can tell **in D3, clicking fires the "drag end" event** (and possibly also drag start?). In the code below, simply clicking the circle gives it a red outline:

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');
var g = svg.append('g');

var c = g.append('circle').attr('r', 20).attr('cx', 25).attr('cy', 25)
         .call(d3.drag().on('drag', dragged).on('end', end))
         .on('click', clicked);

function dragged() {
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'green').attr('cx', d3.event.x).attr('cy', d3.event.y);
}

function end() {
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'red').attr('stroke', 'red').attr('stroke-width', 5);
}

function clicked() {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'blue');
}
```

### [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj21t40n/7/)

#### How do you register a click callback without triggering the drag.end callback?

It seems like most of the questions and blocks about clicking and dragging seem to want to suppress the click action on dragging, so are not relevant.

---

- d3v5.7 (current)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since mouseup indicates a click's completion and the end of a drag you could skip the click event and simply add some logic to determine if a drag occured:

```
// track action:
var wasMoved = false;

// Drag event:
function dragged() {
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'green').attr('cx', d3.event.x).attr('cy', d3.event.y);
    wasMoved = true; // or alternatively, measure the change in distance.
}

// Mouse up event: drag end & click:
function end() {
  if(wasMoved) {
  // It was a drag:
        d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'red').attr('stroke', 'red').attr('stroke-width', 5);
  }
  // Otherwise it was a click:
  else {
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'blue');
  }
  wasMoved = false; // reset for next drag.
}
```

Now we can only trigger one action on mouseup: drag end or what we wanted on click:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');
var g = svg.append('g');

var drag = d3.drag().on("drag", dragged).on("end",end);

var c = g.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 20).attr('cx', 25).attr('cy', 25)
  .call(drag)

var wasMoved = false;

function dragged() {
 d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'green').attr('cx', d3.event.x).attr('cy', d3.event.y);
  wasMoved = true;
}

function end() {
  if(wasMoved) {
  // It was a drag:
  d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'red').attr('stroke', 'orange').attr('stroke-width', 5);
  }
  // It was a click:
  else {
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'blue');
  }
  wasMoved = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I agree this solution works. I had a similar idea of returning early from the `end()` function if the `dragged()` function didn't set a flag (but keeping a separate click handler). But I feel this is inelegant -- and I would assume there's a better way in d3. What do you think? Is there no way around setting a boolean flag?

Comment: There certainly could be a cleaner solution in modifying the d3 source on one line so that click distance could be used to suppress drag-end events in addition to click events (`drag.clickDistance()`) depending on mouse movement. Perhaps I'm tired, but I'm not sure if a cleaner way exists without modification of the source, which may be cleaner but is hardly ideal.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Going to leave this open for a day or two before accepting your answer in case anyone knows of something better. Why do you think modifying the source wouldn't be ideal?

Comment: Well, perhaps I was harsher sounding than intended - just that you introduce an extra source file to export the drag function, and that file won't be updated when d3 is updated (though d3-drag probably won't change that much in the near future minimizing much of any effect). I'll link to an example with a modified source later, it should be cleaner than above.

Comment: Hi Andrew -- no need to do any more work on my account -- I used this workaround. Are we talking about the same thing? I'm suggesting opening a PR against d3-drag. Why wouldn't that be the best long-term fix?

Comment: That would be the more robust solution, I looked through the issues tracker and was a bit surprised it wasn't raised already.