# D3 Click event doesn't work after re-appending path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to recreate [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/versor-dragging) draggable globe from Mike Bostock using D3 but as a svg version. Due to performance issues while dragging I am re-rendering the globe. So far so good. Now I want to implement a click event but it doesn't work. [Here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/click-vs-drag) it is mentioned that the problem might be the re-appending. A mousedown event is working fine but interferes with the dragging later on.
Why is the mousedown event working and the click event not? Hints for restructuring the code to solves this are highly appreciated.

I created a Fiddle for better understanding: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/explorer1/tj5kcahd/3/)

PS. I am new to programming and D3, so please don't be too harsh :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>D3</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="world"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@2"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let width, height
height = 150
width = 150

const projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
    .scale((height - 10) / 2)
    .translate([100, height / 2])
    .precision(0);
let path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)

const svg = d3.select("#world")
    .append("svg")

const g = svg.append("g")

d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-110m.json").then(data =>  {
  let data1 = data
  renderGlobe(data1);
})


function renderGlobe(world){
  g.call(drag(projection)
   .on("drag.render",  ()=>render(world, true))   
   .on("end.render",  ()=>render(world, false)  ))
   .call( () => render(world, false))
}


function render(world, x){
  if(x){
    variable = "land"
     world = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land).features;

  }
  else{
    variable = "countries"
    world = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;
  }
  g.selectAll("path").remove()

  g.selectAll(`${variable}`)
   .data(world)
   .enter().append("path")
   .attr("class", `${variable}`)
   .attr("d", path)
   // This click event doesn't work
   .on("click",()=>console.log("Do something"))
   // But mousedown event works
   .on("mousedown",()=>console.log("Mousedown event works"))
        
}


function drag(projection){
   var LonLatStart, eulerStart
   function dragstarted(event){
      LonLatStart = projection.invert(d3.pointer(event))
  
      eulerStart = projection.rotate()
}

var LonLatEnd, eulerEnd
function dragged(event){
  LonLatEnd = projection.rotate(eulerStart).invert(d3.pointer(event))
  eulerEnd = getEulerAngles(LonLatStart, eulerStart, LonLatEnd)
 
  projection.rotate(eulerEnd)
  refresh()
}
return drag = d3.drag()
  .on("start", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
}

function refresh(){
  svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path)
}

// Dragging Math

  let cos = Math.cos,
  acos = Math.acos,
  sin = Math.sin,
  asin = Math.asin,
  atan2 = Math.atan2,
  sqrt = Math.sqrt,
  min = Math.min,
  max = Math.max,
  PI = Math.PI,
  radians = PI / 180,
  degrees = 180 / PI;

// a: original vector, b: ending vector
function crossProduct(a, b){
  return [
    a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1],
    a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2], 
    a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]
  ]
}

function dotProduct(a, b){
    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1] + a[2] * b[2]    
}

function LengthOfVector(c){
    return sqrt(c[0] * c[0] + c[1] * c[1] + c[2] * c[2])
}

function quaternionEulerFormula(a, b){ 
    let rotationAxis = crossProduct(a,b) , normalizationFactor = sqrt(dotProduct(rotationAxis,rotationAxis))
if (!normalizationFactor) return [1, 0, 0, 0]
    let theta = acos(max(-1, min(1, dotProduct(a, b)))) 
return [
  cos(theta / 2), 
  sin(theta / 2) * rotationAxis[2] / normalizationFactor,
  - sin(theta / 2) * rotationAxis[1] / normalizationFactor,       
  sin(theta / 2) * rotationAxis[0] / normalizationFactor
]
}   

// returns unit quaternion from euler angles [λ, φ, γ]
function unitQuaternion(d){
var lambda = d[0] / 2 * radians, cosLambda = cos(lambda), sinLambda = sin(lambda),
  phi = d[1] / 2 * radians, cosPhi = cos(phi), sinPhi = sin(phi),
  gamma = d[2] / 2 * radians, cosGamma = cos(gamma), sinGamma = sin(gamma)

return [
  cosLambda * cosPhi * cosGamma + sinLambda * sinPhi * sinGamma,
  sinLambda * cosPhi * cosGamma - cosLambda * sinPhi * sinGamma,
  cosLambda * sinPhi * cosGamma + sinLambda * cosPhi * sinGamma,
  cosLambda * cosPhi * sinGamma - sinLambda * sinPhi * cosGamma,
]
}

// quaternion multiplication, returns another quaternion which represents the rotation
function quaternionMultiplication(q0 , q1){
return [
q0[0] * q1[0] - q0[1] * q1[1] - q0[2] * q1[2] - q0[3] * q1[3],
q0[0] * q1[1] + q0[1] * q1[0] + q0[2] * q1[3] - q0[3] * q1[2],
q0[0] * q1[2] - q0[1] * q1[3] + q0[2] * q1[0] + q0[3] * q1[1],
q0[0] * q1[3] + q0[1] * q1[2] - q0[2] * q1[1] + q0[3] * q1[0]
]
}

// converts quaternion to euler angles
function quaternion2eulerAngles(q){
return [
  atan2(2 * (q[0] * q[1] + q[2] * q[3]), 1 - 2 * (q[1] * q[1] + q[2] * q[2])) * degrees,
  //asin(2 * (q[0] * q[2] - q[3] * q[1])) * degrees,
  asin(max(-1, min(1, 2 * (q[0] * q[2] - q[3] * q[1])))) * degrees,
  atan2(2 * (q[0] * q[3] + q[1] * q[2]), 1 - 2 * (q[2] * q[2] + q[3] * q[3])) * degrees
]
}


// converts long, lat to cartesian coordinates x,y,z
function lonlat2cartesian(e) {
let l = e[0] * radians, p = e[1] * radians, cp = cos(p);
return [cp * cos(l), cp * sin(l), sin(p)];
};

function getEulerAngles(positionLonLatStart, eulerAnglesStart, positionLonLatEnd){
let v0 = lonlat2cartesian(positionLonLatStart)
let v1 = lonlat2cartesian(positionLonLatEnd)

let quaternionEnd = quaternionMultiplication(unitQuaternion(eulerAnglesStart), quaternionEulerFormula(v0,v1))
return quaternion2eulerAngles(quaternionEnd)
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the click event? Are you looking to interact with an individual path?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to zoom to the bounding bounds of one path (country). I know how to do the zooming stuff. It worked until I implemented the re-rendering. For the sake of simplicity I didn't add the zooming here.

Comment: Do you want to zoom to the boundary after dragging (no matter how small?) or do you want to zoom only on a proper click (drag distance equal to or roughly 0).

Comment: The zooming should be independent from the dragging. I don't want to zoom after a specific distance dragged. What I want to achieve is to drag freely around the globe and when I click on a country it gets zoomed to the boundary. I hope you understand what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll never trigger the click as is right now, which you've seen. This is because a click involves both mouse down and mouse up. These interact with the drag behavior, with each triggering the start and end events respectively.

What's happening in your case is the mousedown triggers the drag and the mousedown listener you've added to the paths. Then on mouse up, the drag event listener fires first, removing any paths and associated listeners. The render function adds new paths after the fact, too late to register the event.

There are a number of solutions, but perhaps the easiest is to remove the drag end listener you have and replace it only when a drag actually occurs (not in the start event, in the drag event):

```
function renderGlobe(world){
   g.call(drag(projection)
     .on("drag.render",  function(event) {
        render(world, true) 
       event.on("end.render",()=>render(world,false))
   }))
  .call( () => render(world, false))
}
```

The `event.on()` method allows listeners to be applied only for the current gesture. The drag listener only triggers if there is a mousemove between mousedown and mouseup, so this end listener won't be used if there is only a simple click.

Here's a forked [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsp015kz/).

There are a fair number of alternative solutions to this problem, the one here, while simple, may be a bit sensitive to movement during the click. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52841285/7106086)'s a possible basis to an alternative approach to differentiating mouseup related events (click and drag end).